# disable automatic insertion of \selectlanguage and \inputencoding in LyX

Tags: lyx, languages, input-encodings

Is there a way to disable LyX's automatic insertion of `\selectlanguage` and `\inputencoding`?
I like being able to switch languages by hand once in a while, but 99% of the times LyX inserts those commands automatically, it breaks my ERT hacking only since it thinks my opening { is English, while my closing } should be British, or something equally uninteresting.
Today I had some cryptic error because LyX was switching between `\inputencoding{latin1}` and `\inputencoding{latin9}` (I prefer UTF8) and threw in a few braces in less than fortunate places...

I know I can solve issues caused by `\selectlanguage` by resetting language in the "text style" window. Is there a similar quick fix for `\inputencoding` I could use until I can disable its automatic insertion?

To be complete, I use:

Ubuntu 13.04

LyX 2.0.3 (2012-02-19)

Built on Jun  1 2012, 15:14:25

The following example is not exactly what I intended to ask before, but hopefully similar enough. In Lyx everything looks innocent:

```
#LyX 2.0 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 413
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass article
\begin_preamble
\RequirePackage{microtype}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package none
\inputencoding default
\fontencoding global
\font_roman default
\font_sans default
\font_typewriter default
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100

\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize a4paper
\use_geometry false
\use_amsmath 2
\use_esint 1
\use_mhchem 1
\use_mathdots 1
\cite_engine basic
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation skip
\defskip medskip
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
test
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Now, after conversion to tex, with `lyx --export pdflatex test.lyx`, a suspicious `\selectlanguage{english}` appears:

```
%% LyX 2.0.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\RequirePackage{microtype}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}
test

\end{document}
```

and indeed running `pdflatex test.tex` fails:

```
! Package babel Error: You haven't loaded the language english yet.

See the babel package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.23 \selectlanguage{english}

?
```

compiling the pdf from Lyx directly gives the same error.

Comment: I found the \inputencoding was inserted where the language was changed to 'LaTeX', so resetting the language fixes that too.

Comment: This thread describes the same behaviour: [http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.editors.lyx.general/62290].
I fixed my document before posting this question and I can't recall how I got into the situation, so unfortunately I can't post a minimal example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to

> Document Settings > Language

Change `Encoding` to `Other` and select Language Default (no inputenc)`

For language package, select `None`.

[EDIT]
After exporting your `.lyx` file with `pdflatex` I get the following, which does not have `\selectlanguage{english}` and which (as a result) compiles fine:

```
%% LyX 2.0.7dev created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\RequirePackage{microtype}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

I tested on the development versions of `LyX 2.0.x` and `LyX 2.1 beta`. Thus, the problem must have been a bug in LyX that was fixed. Since you are on Ubuntu, it's very easy to use the latest stable version (and/or development version) without having to give up your current version. They can all be installed with no risk. To do this, see the instructions here:
http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LyXOnUbuntu#toc3

Comment: I'm confused; I did what you suggested, but still see `\selectlanguage` in the LaTeX Source Preview. An exported `*.tex` file even has `\usepackage{babel}` in it.
My issue about the _automatic_ inclusion of those bits of code though, and I don't really know when that happens. I believe usually when pasting external text from the clip board, but I can't reproduce it reliably.

Comment: @Roel please see my comment regarding a minimal example.

Comment: I made one. It took a while since most of the time Lyx works very well :)

Comment: @Roel thanks for making the MWE. Yes, sometimes it can take time. But once it's done the answer often pops right out, like in this case.